# Получить значение кубика

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(commands="dice")
async def Dice(m: types.Message):
await m.reply_dice()
```

Мне надо получить значение кубика (dice), который бросил мой бот в ответ на сообщение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я уже нашел ответ:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands="dice")
async def Dice(m: types.Message):
msg=await m.reply_dice() 
print(msg.dice.value)
```

msg.dice.value-значение результата